# How to uninstall cordova plugins in terminal

Tags: xcode, cordova, plugins, terminal

I want remove plugins. I list my plugins

> cordova plugin list

cordova-plugin-calendar 4.4.7 "Calendar" 
cordova-plugin-camera 2.1.1 "Camera" 
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.2 "Console" 
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.0 "Notification" 
cordova-plugin-file 4.1.1 "File"

then

> cordova plugin remove cordoba-plugin-calendar 4.4.7 "Calendar"

I got this error

> Error: Plugin "Calendar" is not present in the project. See `cordova plugin list`.

Where did I mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-calendar
```

regards.

Comment: `cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-calendar` +1